# What's the big O for this triple nested loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Outer loop is O(n), 2nd loop is O(n^2) and 3rd loop is also O(n^2), but the 3rd loop is conditional.

Does that mean the 3rd loop only happens 1/n (1 every n) times and therefore total big O is O(n^4)?

```
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n*n); j++) {
            if (j % i == 0) {
                for (int k = 1; k < (n*n); k++) {
                    // Simple computation
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Technically the algorithm immediately crashes due to division by zero :)

Comment: @TavianBarnes You don't know what language it is <3

Comment: @AChampion: Javascript for one... `x % 0 = NaN`. Hence `NaN !== 0`.

Comment: The last loop will execute for **n** times and each time for **n^2** operations.

Comment: @KhanSaab The innermsot loop will definitely execute much more than n-times. When `i=1` it will repreat `n*n` times, when `i=2` it will repeat `n*n/2` times etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any given value of *i* between 1 and *n*, the complexity of this part:

```
    for (int j = 1; j < (n*n); j++) {
        if (j % i == 0) {
            for (int k = 1; k < (n*n); k++) {
                // Simple computation
            }
        }
    }
```

is *O*(<sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>i</sub>), because the `if`-condition is true one *i*th of the time. (Note: if *i* could be larger than *n*, then we'd need to write *O*(<sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>i</sub> + *n*<sup>2</sup>) to include the cost of the loop iterations where the `if`-condition was false; but since *i* is known to be small enough that <sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>i</sub> ≥ *n*<sup>2</sup>, we don't need to worry about that.)

So the total complexity of your code, adding together the different loop iterations across all values of *i*, is *O*(<sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>1</sub> + <sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>2</sub> + <sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>3</sub> + ⋯ + <sup>*n*<sup>4</sup></sup>/<sub>*n*</sub>) = *O*(*n*<sup>4</sup> · (<sup>1</sup>/<sub>1</sub> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> + ⋯ + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*n*</sub>)) = ***O*(*n*<sup>4</sup> log *n*)**.

(That last bit relies on the fact that, since ln(*n*) is the integral of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*x*</sub> from 1 to *n*, and <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*x*</sub> is decreasing over that interval, we have ln(*n*) < ln(*n*+1) < (<sup>1</sup>/<sub>1</sub> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> + ⋯ + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>*n*</sub>) < 1 + ln(*n*).)

Comment: Your code misses the very outermost loop (there are 3 loops in total). So i think you mean O(n^5 logn)?

Comment: @doctopus: No, I mean what I wrote. I addressed the outermost loop in the paragraph that begins "So the total complexity". (The total complexity is the sum of the complexities of the individual iterations of the outermost loop.)

Comment: Not only is this the correct answer, chances are the connection (that I missed) between mod and log is precisely why this sort of question would be in a homework assignment/test.

Comment: In big-O land all constant log bases are interchangeable because they only differ by constant factors. The harmonic numbers (things of the form 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n) are extremely close to ln n, using log base e.